# Proof help: Coincidences in higher dimensions

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, python, uniform-distribution, beta-distribution

### Background

I recently watched a [2014 Talk](https://youtu.be/rTawFwUvnLE) by [Geoffrey Hinton](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/) (a key researcher in Machine Learning literature) where he discusses the concepts behind the recently published [Capsule Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.09829).

In the talk, he makes the general statement that [coincidences are less likely to occur in higher dimensions](https://youtu.be/rTawFwUvnLE?t=328). Intuitively I can understand that this is a reasonable statement, but I wanted to write a proof to convince myself.

### Numeric Proof (Python script)

First I wrote a python script to numerically prove this.

```py
"""
test_highdim.py
Hinton says in a 2014 MIT presentation that 'conincidences are less likely to
occur in higher dimensional spaces'. This script tests this hypothesis.
"""

import numpy as np

def main():
    # Gist of the numerical proof:
    # epsilon = some float
    #
    # Start with m=1, M>>m
    # While loop:
    #   Generate a random point in R^m
    #   If this point is closer than epsilon to any other previous point, break
    # Print how many times we looped
    # Increase m to a higher dimension and go again until m=M

    log_file = "test_highdim.csv"
    open(log_file, 'w').close()

    epsilon = 0.5
    max = 1
    min = 0
    M = 400

    # What norm to use when finding distances (L1=1, L2=2 etc.)
    norm_ordinance = 2

    for m in range(1, M):

        # Run at each dimension (m) a few times to get an average measure
        average_n = 0.0
        num_runs = 100
        for j in range(num_runs):

            # Create a new empty array of R^m points
            n = 0
            pts = np.empty(shape=(0, m), dtype=float)
            coincidence_occured = False

            # Loop
            while True:

                # Pick a new random uniform point in R^m
                r = np.random.uniform(low=min, high=max, size=m)

                # See if this point is close to any previous point
                for i in range(pts.shape[0]):
                    d = np.linalg.norm(pts[i, :], ord=norm_ordinance)

                    # If so, we got a coincidence
                    if d <= epsilon:
                        # Break
                        coincidence_occured = True
                        break

                # Add the point, and increment our counter      
                pts = np.append(pts, [r], axis=0)
                n += 1

                if coincidence_occured == True:
                    break

            average_n += n

        average_n /= num_runs

        print("R^%d: Took %f iterations" % (m, average_n))
        with open(log_file, mode='a') as f:
            f.write("%d, %.3f\n" % (m, average_n))
            f.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As expected, when I graph the output with $m$ (the dimension) on the x axis, I see some kind of stochastic exponential growth in the number of iterations it takes ($n$) to find a coincidence.

[image: Graph of n (number of random uniform draws to find a coincidence) vs m (dimension)]

I want to find a closed form probabilistic expression for that relationship. My work-in-progress proof is below.

### Proof attempt

The gist of my proof is as follows; Sampling uniform random points in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ is the same as sampling $n \over m$ uniform randoms in $\mathbb{R}^m$, provided each dimension is independent. I consider that a coincidence has ocurred if two random points are close together. I then try and find a probability expression for how likely this is to occur after $n$ random draws. More formally;

Consider a random sample $(U_1, ... U_n)$ of i.i.d. random uniform draws on the range $[0, 1]$. In this situation $n$ draws can be considered identical to $n \over m$ draws from multinomial uniform random variables in $\mathbb{R}^m$ as each dimension's draw is independent. Let $U_{(1)}, ... U_{(n)}$ denote the order statistics of the sample such that $U_{(1)} = min(U_i)$ and $U_{(n)} = max(U_i)$.

Wikipedia's [Order Statistic page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Order_statistics_sampled_from_a_uniform_distribution) then tells me that $U_{(k)} \sim Beta(k, n+k-1)$ for $k = 1, ... n$.

If $\epsilon$ is some small value, I then state that a coincidence occurs when the expected values of $m$ order statistics are less than $\epsilon$ apart, which I believe is equivalent to using the L1 norm or 'Manhattan distance' in $\mathbb{R}^m$.

$$
E[U_{k+m)}] - E[U_{k}] \leq \epsilon;\quad
\begin{aligned}
k &= 1, ... n-m,\\
n &> m
\end{aligned}
$$

Using the [expected value of a beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#mean), I then simplify;

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{k + m}{n+1} - \frac{k}{n+1} &\leq \epsilon \\ \\
\frac{k + m - k}{n + 1} &\leq \epsilon \\ \\
n &\ge \frac{m}{\epsilon}-1
\end{aligned}
$$

When I re-run my numeric solution using the L1 norm, it doesn't match the values predicted by my proof at all (more than I would expect from stochastic noise).

[image: Graph of n (number of random uniform draws to find a coincidence) vs m (dimension)]

### Questions

1. Is my proof correct if I use the L1 norm?
2. How would I generalize this to use any norm?
3. I feel like this result should have already been proved, but I don't know what to search for to find a proof. What terms should I be looking for?

This is my first attempt at writing a proof ever. Please be gracious with your feedback :)

Comment: Firstly, I don't get why you define distance between two points as $E[U_{(m+k)}] - E[U_{(k)}]$. Why do you need to invoke ordering at all - is that some shortcut I don't notice? Secondly, consider that the discrete case is much easier to prove (and of course less interesting), because you don't need norms, just a probability to draw two identical points from some multi-dimensional distribution.

Comment: Hi @joud - I define distance that way (invoking ordering) because I wanted to check if $m$ draws are near to each other. Without ordering $\mathbb{E}[U(0, 1)]$ just 0.5 so I would get an expression that was $0.5 - 0.5 \leq \epsilon$ or something like that. I'll try your suggestion and consider the discrete case...

Comment: Yes, so I don't see how calculating expectations of (ordered or unordered) positions should lead to probability of coincidence. L1 norm is $\sum_{i=1}^m | U_{1,i} - U_{2,i} |$, so you should aim to get the c.d.f. or expectation of this expression. But working with L2 norm would be easier, and with discrete distributions - easier still.